# Recursive Substrings out of bounds error

Tags: java, recursion, substring

I have to create a recursive method to display all substrings of a given string before the letter 'A' or 'a', and ignore that letter in the process.  The termination condition works fine.  However, in the continue condition I am thrown a indexoutofbounds error and I'm not entirely sure why.  As far as I can tell I stop the loop before the index reaches the string's length.  but I will post it here in case I missed something.

```
class Tree
{
    void subStrings(String s)
    {
        if(s.length() == 1)
        {
            if(s.charAt(0) == 'A' || s.charAt(0) == 'a')
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot shorten substring.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

        }

        else
        {
            String subString = "";
            int i = 0;
            while(s.charAt(i) != 'A' && i < s.length())//bad line
            {   
                subString += s.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }

            if(subString.equals(""))
                subStrings(s.substring(i));
            else
            {
                System.out.println(subString);
                subStrings(s.substring(i));
            }
        }
    }

    int treeHeight(String tree)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're just splitting a string using `A` or `a` as a delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even Robby's refactoring won't get you where you won't on account of some other issues. For what concerns your exception you must iterate to `i < s.length() - 1` since you're incrementing the index in the loop, and charAt method you use inside the loop starts at index 0.

Checked further and you should change your `substring(i)` to  `subStrings(s.substring(0, i))` otherwise you would end up with the same string in recursion. The following should work for you

```
    void subStrings(String s)
    {
        if(s == null || s.length() == 0 || s.charAt(0) == 'A' || s.charAt(0) == 'a')
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot shorten substring.");
            return;
        }
        if(s.length() != 1)
        {
            String subString = "";
            int i = 0;
            while(s.charAt(i) != 'A' && s.charAt(i) != 'a' && i < s.length() - 1)//bad line
            {
                subString += s.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }


            if(subString.equals(""))
                subStrings(s.substring(i));
            else
            {
                System.out.println(subString);
                subStrings(s.substring(0, i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: From the way the termination is set now, the program doesn't grab anything passed the first 'A' or 'a' that is encountered.

Comment: After modifying a few things I found that setting the termination condition to being just s.length() <= 1 and dealing with the 'a' and 'A' inside was best, and for the case of the substring turning up null the recursive method should pass (i + 1).  Your code was very helpful by the way, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse these two conditions:

```
while(s.charAt(i) != 'A' && i < s.length()) { /*...*/ }
```

So, it should be:

```
while(i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) != 'A') { /*...*/ }
```

Otherwise you get an out of bounds exception when the string is empty and you try to access the first character (at position 0).

---

If you just want to [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) a string using `a` or `A` as a delimiter, you might as well do:

```
String[] substrings = str.split("[aA]");
```

If it absolutely has to be implemented using a recursive method, instead of processing the string character by character, you could use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) to find the position of the next `a` or `A`. It could look something like this:

```
public static void subStrings(String s) {
    int i = s.toLowerCase().indexOf('a');

    if (i >= 0) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, i));

        if (i + 1 < s.length()) {
            subStrings(s.substring(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the loop to have the indexOf statements, but now I'm throwing a StackOverflow error.  Never dealt with this error before so I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: StackOverflowError means (in nearly all cases) infinite recursion. Your termination is not working correctly.